# missing value in a column using DATEADD function in dax power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, missing-data, dateadd

[image]

is anybody knows why the second cell in previousdate column is empty and how I can solve this?

It how it works with PREVOUSQUARTER function:
[image]

Comment: I resolved this problem partially using function called previousquarter. But still do not undarstand this missing value in the second cell

Comment: Is your CALENDAR table created from the [data] column? Formula I suppose something like "calendar(firstdate('table'[data]),lastdate('table'[data]))" so you got the Calendar table starts from 2022-03-31. Then when you use DATEADD formula there is no dates till 2022-03-31 so these two first cells with 2022-01-31 / 2022-03-30 which are before the table start date cannot show. You can try to change start date of CALENDAR table such as 2022-01-01 to see if it works.

Comment: @Sia - I think THIS is their calendar table. I'm surprised PREVIOUSQUARTER works. I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: @DavideBacci Hi Davide, you got me clear. I just tested with PREVIOUSQUARTER and found it does not work. Hi Piotrek, Would you kindly let me see your result? Just curious. Thanks!

Comment: @Sia I added picture how it works with PREVIOUSQUARTER. I was expected the same result with DATEADD but I can see it works slightly different.

Comment: @Piotrek But you still miss the first cell. Show you steps with image in ANSWER below if you need first cell can take a look.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Create a new table:**

```
Calendar 2 = CALENDAR(DATE(2021,1,1),LASTDATE('Calendar'[Data]))
```

**2. Set relationship between two tables in MODEL view:**

[image]

**3. Calculate previousdate:**

```
previousdate = DATEADD('Calendar 2'[Date],-1,QUARTER)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What if you use DATEADD() instead? I think the reason you're not seeing some values is that those dates are not in your calendar table.